# Show that $\mathbb{R}P^5$ and $ \mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5$ have the same fundamental group and homology group.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Show that $\mathbb{R}P^5$ and $ \mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5$ have the same fundamental group and homology groups. Show they are not homotopy equivalent, because they have different higher homotopy groups.

**Hints:**

1- $S^n$ is a covering space of $\mathbb{R}P^n$.

2- For the last part of Problem 6,  show that $\pi_4(\mathbb{R}P^5)=0$,but $\pi_4(\mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5)$ is non-zero.  You can do this by arguing that $S^5 \vee S^4 \vee S^5$ is a covering space of $\mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5$ and then show $S^4$ is a retract of $S^5 \vee S^4 \vee S^5.$  You may assume $\pi_4(S^4)$ is isomorphic to the integers.

**My questions are:**

1- How can I prove that they have the same fundamental group?

2- How can I prove that they have the same homology group?

3- How can I argue that $S^5 \vee S^4 \vee S^5$ is a covering space of $\mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5$?

4- How can I show $S^4$ is a retract of $S^5 \vee S^4 \vee S^5$?

Could anyone help me in answering these questions please?

Comment: Any thought/effort about your 4 questions?

Comment: yes I have @ArcticChar I will edit my question

Comment: I think for my fourth question, I can take the inclusion map @ArcticChar correct?

Comment: 1) Do you know the fundamental group of the projective spaces? To compute it for the wedge, use Seifert van Kampen. 2) Do you know the homology of projective spaces? For the other, use Mayer Vietoris sequence. 4) There is an obvious map S^4\rightarrow S^5\vee S^4\vee S^5, namely the inclusion. Can you define a map the other way?

Comment: So elegant and precise hints @ThomasRot thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer might be overkill considering that the body of OP's question only asks for answers to 4 subproblems, but for completeness it might be worth it to spell out the solution to the whole question in the subject. (I recommend you first try to work out for yourself the hints in Thomas Rot's comment and then put the results together, because this answer just does that.)

---

This answer assumes that the following result is available, because it is very useful for this problem: if $\rho\colon E\to B$ is a covering map of connected spaces then the projection map induces an inclusion $\rho_*\colon \pi_1 E \hookrightarrow \pi_1 B$ whose image has index $n$, and $\pi_i E \cong \pi_i B$ for $i > 1$. (This can be proven using only material from Hatcher's AT Chapter 1, in particular see Propositions 1.31, 1.32 and 4.1. It also follows immediately from the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for a fibration. )

**Answers to your questions (based on the hints):**

1) The quotient map $S^n \to \mathbb{R}P^n$ is a 2-sheeted covering space for every $n$, so it follows from the assumed result that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ for $n > 1$ since $S^n$ is simply connected in this range. Then by the [Seifert-van Kampen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem) 
$$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5) \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^4) * \pi_1(S^5) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^5) $$

2) The [homology of real projective space](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Homology_of_real_projective_space) $\mathbb{R}P^n$ consists of $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree $0$, $\mathbb{Z}/2$ in every odd degree $<n$, $0$ in all even degrees, and if $n$ is odd then it is orientable so there is also a $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree $n$. Moreover, by a [Mayer-Vietoris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence) argument it follows that $H_i(X\vee Y) \cong H_i(X)\oplus H_i(Y)$ for all pointed spaces $X$ and $Y$ and all degrees $i > 0$. Since $\mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5$ is connected, we get the graded group isomorphisms

$$ H_\bullet(\mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus 0 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus 0 \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus 0 \oplus \dots \cong H_\bullet(\mathbb{R}P^5)$$

3) Note that the quotient map $S^4 \to \mathbb{R}P^4$ identifies the antipodal points in the sphere. Form the space $X$ by attaching one copy of $S^5$ to $S^4$ at the south pole $S$, and another copy of $S^5$ at the north pole $N$ (note that strictly speaking this is not the coproduct of pointed spaces $S^5\vee S^4\vee S^5$ because there are multiple attaching points, but they are homotopy equivalent). Then since the antipodal map identifies $S$ and $N$ we can construct a function $X \to \mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5$ by taking the quotient map on $S^4$ and have the attached copies of $S^5$ map to $S^5$ by the identity. Away from the wedge point in $\mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5$ it's clear that that every point is evenly covered by 2 sheets (use small charts). If $x_0$ is the wedge point, then since $\mathbb{R}P^4$ and $S^5$ are both manifolds we can choose open balls $U_1$ and $U_2$ containing $x_0$ from each space, and let $U = U_1 \cup U_2$. If $U_1$ is small enough then its inverse image is two open balls $\tilde{U}_1, \tilde{U}_1'$ in $S^4$, and the inverse image of $U_2$ will be two copies $\tilde{U}_2, \tilde{U}_2'$ of itself, one in each copy of $S^5$. The inverse image of $U$ is then the disjoint union of $\tilde{U}_1 \vee \tilde{U}_2$ and $\tilde{U}_1' \vee \tilde{U}_2'$.

4) Recall that a subspace $A\subset X$ is a [retract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract) if there is a continuous function $r \colon X \to A$ such that $r|_A = id_A$. Notice that any wedge-summand is a retract, since we can continuously define $A\vee B \to A$ by mapping $A$ identically to itself and $B$ to the wedge point; in particular $S^4$ is a retract of $S^5\vee S^4 \vee S^5$. Note that if $A \stackrel{i}{\hookrightarrow} X \stackrel{r}{\to} A$ is a retract and $\pi_k(A) \neq 0$ for some $k$, then $\pi_k(X)$ is also non-zero since functoriality of $\pi_k$ gives a factorization $id_{\pi_k A} = \pi_k(r) \circ \pi_k(i)$.

**Putting it all together:** 1) and 2) say that $\mathbb{R}P^4\vee S^5$ and $\mathbb{R}P^5$ have the same fundamental group and homology groups. However, we can show they are not homotopy equivalent by using 3) and 4) to show they have different $\pi_4$. First, since $S^5$ is a covering space of $\mathbb{R}P^5$ they have the same higher homotopy groups, and in particular $\pi_4\mathbb{R}P^5 \cong \pi_4 S^5 = 0$. On the other hand, since $E = S^5 \vee S^4 \vee S^5$ is (homotopy equivalent to) a 2-sheeted covering of $\mathbb{R}P^4\vee S^5$ it suffices to compute $\pi_4 E$. Since we have a retraction $S^4 \stackrel{i}{\hookrightarrow} E \stackrel{r}{\to} S^4$ and $\pi_4 S^4 \cong \mathbb{Z}$ if follows from point 4) that $\pi_4 E$ is non-zero. Therefore $\pi_4(\mathbb{R}P^4\vee S^5) \not\cong \pi_4 \mathbb{R}P^5$.

Comment: Could you please tell us this first result you assume it is available is at which page of AT?

Comment: In Hatcher it looks like Theorem 4.41 on page 376 has the statement for the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for a (Serre) fibration, which applies in particular to fibre bundles and hence covering spaces. If $F$ is discrete (like a covering space) and $B$ and $E$ are connected then the result I stated follows.

Comment: Can we speak about 3 without using the property that S^5 and RP^5 are manifolds

Comment: @Emptymind I think maybe yes. I think if $E \to B$ is a covering space and $Z$ another space and we form the space $X$ by wedging a copy of $Z$ onto every point in a fibre, then it should be possible to verify that $Z \to B \vee X$ is a covering space.

Comment: Can we use instead of thm.4,41 you mentioned Proposition 4.1 on pg.342?

Comment: or because we need the fundamental group (n = 1) we should use thm4.41 ?

Comment: in showing that they have same fundamental group, how are you sure that the assumptions of Van Kampen theorem are satisfied?

Comment: Yes you could use Prop 4.1 for the result that a covering space has the same higher homotopy groups; you can probably also get the result I state for $\pi_1$ using material from chapter 1. The open sets I'm thinking of for van Kampen are constructed as follows: let $U_1$ be a contractible neighbourhood of the basepoint in $\mathbb{R}P^4$ and $U_2$ a contractible neighbourhood of the basepoint in $S^5$, then take the open path-connected sets $U_1 \vee S^5$ and $\mathbb{R}P^4\vee U_2$, whose intersection $U_1 \vee U_2$ is contractible.

Comment: For the $\pi_1$ statement look at Propositions 1.31 and 1.32. In fact, the proof of Proposition 4.1 also only uses material from Chapter 1, where it is established that covering spaces have the homotopy lifting property. (Theorem 4.41 applies more generally to *any* map $E\to B$ with the homotopy lifting property (with respect to disks).)

Comment: For 2) the first features of the real projective plane you mentioned I can see them from Example 2.4 on pg.106. but starting from saying that "if n is odd then it is orientable ....." I do not know from where did you get these piece of information , could you please tell me from which page in AT you got this? Also, why if n is odd then it is orientable ?

Comment: Also, for 2) I can not see that Mayer Vietoris has Wedge sum I think it has intersection on pg149.

Comment: Hatcher computes the cellular homology of real projective space in example 2.42 on page 144, the idea is the antipodal map $S^k \to S^k$ is the composition of $k+1$ reflections so it has degree $-1$ if $k$ is even and $1$ if $k$ is odd (this is why odd-dimensional projective space is orientable). For the Mayer-Vietoris argument for $\mathbb{R}P^4\vee S^5$, use the same open set decomposition that we used for van Kampen (if $\{X_\alpha\}$ is a family of pointed spaces such that each basepoint has a contractible neighbourhood then $H_i(\vee X_\alpha) \cong \oplus_\alpha H_i(X_\alpha)$ for $i>0$)

Comment: Can you draw a picture for explaining why E is homotopy equivalent to a 2 sheeted covering of $RP^4 \vee S^5$?

Comment: I constructed the space $X$ in part 3) to be a double cover of $\mathbb{R}P^4 \vee S^5$. The "picture" describing a homotopy equivalence between $E=S^5 \vee S^4 \vee S^5$ and $X$ is just that you choose a path from the basepoint in $S^4$ to the antipode of the basepoint,  and drag one of the copies of $S^5$ along this path.