# Why $H_5(\mathbb{R}P^5) = \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Why $H_5(\mathbb{R}P^5) = \mathbb{Z}$?

Can anyone describe it for me using the formula $H_{n} = \frac {\ker{\partial_{n}}}{Im{\partial_{n+1}}}.$ I know that this is correct because it is orientable but I need a proof by the above mentioned formula.

Comment: Do you know the theory of cellular homology? The computation of homology of projective space becomes quite transparent under the view point of cellular homology. You may want to google it.

Comment: is not it using the same formula I mentioned in my question above @qubinggang?

Comment: Yes and No. In cellular homology you pruduce "cellular complex" of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ which is much more simpler. And there is theorem ensuring that the homology group computed by cellular complex is equal to the homology group computed by singular complex.

Comment: Okay, sounds good, so what is the answer to my question? @qubinggang

Comment: The cellular complex is indeed computed from the same formula, but from a different comlex.

Comment: If I didn't go wrong. The cellular complex of $\mathbb{R}P^5$ is $0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow 0$ with $\mathrm{d}_5=0$. So $H_5=\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{d_5})=\mathbb{Z}$. Happier? :)

Comment: I do not understand this solution unfortunately @qubinggang can you do it by the formula I mentioned in my question please?

Comment: @Secretly could you write down what is the domain and target of $\partial$ you've been mentioning in your post. Depending on that we can answer what kind of homology theory you are using and then we can help you

Comment: $\partial_{5}$ has domain 0 and target $\mathbb{Z}$ if I am not mistaken @Mihail

Comment: How have you come up with this result?

Comment: No, I know that the result is correct but I did not get it .... I get 0 instead @Mihail

Comment: There are different homology theories and we do not know which one exactly you need. Well, even though some of them are equivalent the calculations depend on the theory. Where did you get this question from?

Comment: @Mihail this result is mentioned here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3426826/show-that-mathbbrp5-and-mathbbrp4-vee-s5-have-the-same-fundamenta  in 2) in the given answer.